# <input type="time" step="1"> not returning seconds in .value in Chromium

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, event-handling

Consider the following input field

```js
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener(
  "change",
  function(e) {
    document.getElementById("div").textContent = e.target.value;
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="time" step="1" value="00:00:00" id="inp" />
<div id="div">00:00:00</div>
```

When tested in Firefox, the value is what I expect when the input is changed -- the format is hh:mm:ss. But when tested in Chromium (67.0.3396.99), when the input is changed to anything that has 0 seconds, e.g. 01:00:00, the value attribute only returns hh:mm.

Is this correct / intended behaviour as per the specs? (Edit: It is.) And the main question: Is there a standard way that I'm unaware of, that is more preferable than `.value`, to get its value in hh:mm:ss, or do I have to resort to some JavaScript string parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth the JavaScript string parsing is very simple and straight-forward to implement:

```js
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener(
  "change",
  function(e) {
    let time = e.target.value;
    if (time.length < 6) { // missing :ss on chrome
      time += ':00'; // add it ourselves
    }
    document.getElementById("div").textContent = time;
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="time" step="1" value="00:00:00" id="inp" />
<div id="div">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: I was reluctant to do it this way because it felt too "hacky" and may fail in weird cases. After being linked to the updated specs it seems, at least for a standard-compliant browser, that this is the way to do it (maybe check for empty string first). To me, the optional fraction of a second part is not a big problem, but string length checks can also work if it is.  I will leave this question open for a few days, if there's no better answer I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

The outputs of Firefox and Chromium are actually both consistent with the specs.

The [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#time-state-(type=time)) (Last Updated 24 July 2018) states:

> The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a valid time string.

And "valid time string" is [defined](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-time-string) as follows:

> A string is a **valid time string** representing an hour *hour*, a minute
>   *minute*, and a second *second* if it consists of the following components
>   in the given order:
>
> 1. Two ASCII digits, representing *hour*, in the range 0 ≤ *hour* ≤ 23
> 2. A U+003A COLON character (:)
> 3. Two ASCII digits, representing *minute*, in the range 0 ≤ *minute* ≤ 59
> 4. If *second* is nonzero, or optionally if *second* is zero:
>
>    1. A U+003A COLON character (:)
>    2. Two ASCII digits, representing the integer part of *second*, in the range 0 ≤ *s* ≤ 59
>    3. If *second* is not an integer, or optionally if *second* is an integer:
>
>       1. A U+002E FULL STOP character (.)
>       2. One, two, or three ASCII digits, representing the fractional part of *second*

<sub>Credits to user @int32_t for linking me to the current standard.</sub>

Comment: It's very very very old working draft.  The latest specification is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#time-state-(type=time) , and the second part is optional.

Comment: @int32_t Thanks for the link. I blame Google for giving me the old one.